# Delay iframes on page load, append parameters, then show iframes after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

Here's the issue: My site is slow and it's because of iframes. Due to that, I want to delay the iframes loading until the rest of the page loads. However, I also need to append a bunch of parameters to the `iframe src` before it appears to a visitor. So here's the order of things that need to happen:

1. Page loads with all the crucial things for a visitor to see (CSS, text, images, etc.)
2. Delay the load of the iframes about 5 seconds, to make sure the whole page loads, and the iframes don't slow down the loading time (could use `setTimeout`?)
3. Append a bunch of parameters to the `iframe src` via JavaScript
4. Then allow the iframe to appear on the page

For the sake of context, here's the website: http://meetingtomorrow.com/ (the iframe is actually a form that appears after you click the blue "Request a Quote" sidetab). There are also often 2 other iframes that appear on the page: an exit intent form and another quote form.

Here's how we're currently initiating the function to append parameters to the `iframe src` on the site:

`<body onload="populateHiddenFields(document.forms['ga-tracking-form'])">`

And here's how we're currently appending the parameters to the iframe src:

```
function populateHiddenFields() { 
    jQuery('form#ga-tracking-form').each(function (index, element) {

        var f = this;

        f.source.value  = source; 
        f.medium.value  = medium; 
        f.term.value    = term; 
        f.content.value = content; 
        f.campaign.value = campaign;
        f.gclid.value = gclid; 
        f.segment.value = csegment;
        f.numVisits.value = nVisits;  

    });     

    var loc = window.location.toString();
params = loc.split('?')[1];     

    document.getElementById("nsIframeSidetab").src = document.getElementById("nsIframeSidetab").src + '&custentity_web_lead_nab_parameter=' + encodeURIComponent(params) + '&custentity_ga_search_campaign=' + encodeURIComponent(campaign) + '&custentity_ga_search_source=' + encodeURIComponent(source) + '&custentity_ga_search_medium=' + encodeURIComponent(medium) + '&custentity_ga_search_keyword=' + encodeURIComponent(term) + '&custentity_ga_search_content=' + encodeURIComponent(content) + '&custentity_ga_search_gclid=' + encodeURIComponent(gclid);

    document.getElementById("nsIframeExitIntent").src = document.getElementById("nsIframeExitIntent").src + '&custentity_web_lead_nab_parameter=' + encodeURIComponent(params) + '&custentity_ga_search_campaign=' + encodeURIComponent(campaign) + '&custentity_ga_search_source=' + encodeURIComponent(source) + '&custentity_ga_search_medium=' + encodeURIComponent(medium) + '&custentity_ga_search_keyword=' + encodeURIComponent(term) + '&custentity_ga_search_content=' + encodeURIComponent(content) + '&custentity_ga_search_gclid=' + encodeURIComponent(gclid);

    document.getElementById("nsIframe").src = document.getElementById("nsIframe").src + '&custentity_web_lead_nab_parameter=' + encodeURIComponent(params) + '&custentity_ga_search_campaign=' + encodeURIComponent(campaign) + '&custentity_ga_search_source=' + encodeURIComponent(source) + '&custentity_ga_search_medium=' + encodeURIComponent(medium) + '&custentity_ga_search_keyword=' + encodeURIComponent(term) + '&custentity_ga_search_content=' + encodeURIComponent(content) + '&custentity_ga_search_gclid=' + encodeURIComponent(gclid);

    return false;
```

One final piece of key information. This is the actual iframe code:

`<iframe id="nsIframeSidetab" src="<?php echo 'https://forms.na2.netsuite.com/app/site/crm/externalleadpage.nl?compid=3373305&formid=65&h=AACffht_oVPvzBS2Q5xRFMm3YXYganqAV-g%3D&url=' . rawurlencode( get_permalink()); ?>" width="100%" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>`

Part of the difficulty here is that the `iframe src` itself is using a PHP function to dynamically populate the first part of the URL. It's a WordPress site, so it's pulling in the permalink (URL of the current page). Then after that permalink, the rest of the parameters are appended to the URL via JavaScript. Hopefully that all makes sense.

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to do this (steps #1-4 above) would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I don't see where are the iframes... But there are a couple errors like `Unexpected token (`, `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=#]`, `Cannot read property 'src' of null`, and so on... That you should fix first. Hit [F12] to open the console.

Comment: I have no idea why are you using iframes here. Anyway, setting an iframe src to just changing it few moment later doesn't really make sense. Just set a variable string, concatenate whatever you need as parameter and then set it as iframe src only once it has all needed parameters added

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thanks for your comment. The iframes are hidden from view to start with. If you click the blue "Request a Quote" tab on the right side, the form that appears is in an iframe. Also, if it's the first time you've visited the site (or you've cleared your cache), an "exit intent" form will popup, and that's an iframe as well. Thanks -

Comment: @A.Wolff We're forced to use iframes because the forms they need are from NetSuite, their sales/customer management software, and they need to embed them on the page. With that said, I can look into setting the src once, which may help. However, I still need to delay the loading of the iframes for several seconds, so that the page doesn't get held up. Right now it's very slow to load, and a major reason for that is these iframe forms. Any thoughts on how to delay the loading of the iframes? Thanks -

Comment: I agree with @A. Wolff... If you want some part of your site to be updated later... Based on whatever input from the user OR simply because the info you look for is in another file, Look for Ajax.

Comment: I just saw your comment to A. Wolf... We were writing at the same moment, I suppose. Look for a `proxie` method then... with `file_get_contents()` and an Ajax request, to get your "sales/customer management software" page. ;)